# Troubleshooting D3 bar chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm digging into D3 for the first time and am **trying to create a small multiples of bar charts** to visualize some research regarding the consumption of food items over time. Using some examples online, I've managed to get area charts to work just fine. But bar charts will let me understand the data better. I feel like the code I have so far is close to working, but I'm clearly missing something. Any tips or assistance would be wonderful.

By example, here's a snippet of my .csv file:

```
group,date,totals
acid,1641,8438
bird,1641,12
cheese,1641,22
cured meat,1641,506
dried fish,1644,158
fresh fish,1644,1196
meat,1644,140
brined/pickled fish,1645,2844
salt,1645,4382
...
```

The code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 500 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 150 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

// scales
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// for the area charts example, an area generator
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.totals); });

// for the area charts example, a line generator
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.totals); });

// load data
d3.csv("revised.csv", function(error, data) {

  // nest values by group
  var groups = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.group; })
      .entries(data);

  // parse dates and numbers, assume values are sorted by date
  // compute the maximum totals per group
  groups.forEach(function(s) {
    s.values.forEach(function(d) { d.date = parse(d.date); d.totals = +d.totals; });
    s.maxtotals = d3.max(s.values, function(d) { return d.totals; });
  });

  // compute the minimum and maximum date across groups
  x.domain([
    d3.min(groups, function(s) { return s.values[0].date; }),
    d3.max(groups, function(s) { return s.values[s.values.length - 1].date; })
  ]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.totals; })]);

  // add an SVG element for each group
  var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("g")
      .data(groups)
    .enter().append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // print x axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));
  // print y axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

    // Trying here to render my bar charts. 
    // -----------------------------------
    svg.selectAll(".bar")
       .data(groups)
     .enter().append("rect")
       .attr("x", x)
       .attr("y", function(d) { return d.maxtotals; })
       .attr("width", width / groups.length)
       .attr("height", function(d) { return d.maxtotals; });

// These are the area charts, that work. Commented out for now.
  //svg.append("path")
  //    .attr("class", "area")
  //    .attr("d", function(d) { y.domain([0, d.maxtotals]); return area(d.values); });

  //svg.append("path")
  //    .attr("class", "bar")
  //    .attr("d", function(d) { y.domain([0, d.maxtotals]); return line(d.values); });


  // Add a small label for the group name.
  svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 6)
      .attr("y", height - 6)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
});

</script>
```

The area charts look something like this at the moment (the above code has changed the way these look, but it gives you an idea):

[image: Screen grab]

Any pointers? What am I overlooking? Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to some amazing help from [Elijah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350344/elijah), we managed to get this working. Here's the revision:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 400 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 150 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

// scales
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, height]);

// load data
d3.csv("revised.csv", function(error, data) {

  // nest values by group
  var groups = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.group; })
      .entries(data);

  // parse dates and numbers, assume values are sorted by date
  // compute the maximum totals per group
  groups.forEach(function(s) {
    s.values.forEach(function(d) { d.date = parse(d.date); d.totals = +d.totals; });
    s.maxtotals = d3.max(s.values, function(d) { return d.totals; });
  });

  // compute the minimum and maximum date across groups
  x.domain([
    d3.min(groups, function(s) { return s.values[0].date; }),
    d3.max(groups, function(s) { return s.values[s.values.length - 1].date; })
  ]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.totals; })]);

  // add an SVG element for each group
  var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("g")
      .data(groups)
    .enter().append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .each(function(d) {
          var g = d3.select(this);
          g.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  y.domain([0, d3.max(d.values, function(r) { return r.totals; })]);

  g.selectAll("rect.aevents")
    .data(d.values)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("height", function(p) {return y(p.totals)})
    .attr("width", 5)
    .attr("x", function(p, q) {return x(p.date)})
    .attr("y", function(p) {return height - y(p.totals)})
    .on("click", function(p) {console.log(p.date.year())})
    // .attr("class", "bar")
    })

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

  // Add a small label for the group name.
  svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 6)
      .attr("y", height - 6)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d.key; });

});

</script>
```

The main changes: the `.each()` function is added to the SVG as a `g` element, which calls `data.values` as its data. The `y()` scale has also been flipped (from `0,h` to `h,0`). My other oversight was the `.each()` function had contained the `d3.max()` function within it, so the max total for each item group was checked for a single group rather than all groups as a whole. Now, instead of area charts, I have nicely rendered bar charts that display total amounts for each food group.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that pops out at me is that you're not applying your `y` scale to `d.maxtotals` in both your `"y"` and `"height"` attributes, nor are you scaling the `"width"` attribute appropriately. Because of the way that you're determining these attribute values, it should be as simple as applying the scales to the values you're already returning. Just note that in the future, this may not work in general.

Another problem is that you probably don't mean for the `"y"` attribute to be related to your data at all. That's `"height"`'s job. Set they `"y"` attribute to the same y-coordinate you're giving your x-axis.